# Julia - DataFrames Insert a Row at Specific index in Julia 1.1

Tags: dataframe, insert, julia

How can I insert a row in a dataframe in Julia at a specific index ? (Julia version 1.1)

I have found [this related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51505007/julia-dataframes-insert-new-row-at-specific-index) However, the code given in the answer isn't working anymore in Julia 1.1

I know how to push! a row into a dataframe or concatenate two dataframes, but what about inserting at a specific index ?

It also doesn't seem to be explained in [Julia DataFrames documentation](https://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/index.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a non-standard operation. The recommendation given there is still valid, so:

```
df = DataFrame(x = [1,2,3], y = ["a", "b", "c"])
foreach((v,n) -> insert!(df[n], 2, v), [4, "d"], names(df))
```

works. A shorter version to write it under Julia 1.0 would be:

```
insert!.(eachcol(df, false), 2, [4, "d"])
```

(the need to add `false` as a second argument will not be needed in the future as we are in the deprecation period now)

The difference is that `getproperty` method can be overloaded since Julia 1.0 so `df.columns` does not work.

I have also updated the other answer, so you can close this question if you prefer.

#### EDIT

The instructions above are no longer valid (unless you use very old DataFrames.jl version).

In DataFrames.jl 1.4 use `insert!`, `push!`, or `pushfirst!` functions depending on where you want to add the row:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(x = [1,2,3], y = ["a", "b", "c"])
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ x      y
     │ Int64  String
─────┼───────────────
   1 │     1  a
   2 │     2  b
   3 │     3  c

julia> insert!(df, 2, (100, "new line"))
4×2 DataFrame
 Row │ x      y
     │ Int64  String
─────┼─────────────────
   1 │     1  a
   2 │   100  new line
   3 │     2  b
   4 │     3  c

julia> push!(df, (200, "last line"))
5×2 DataFrame
 Row │ x      y
     │ Int64  String
─────┼──────────────────
   1 │     1  a
   2 │   100  new line
   3 │     2  b
   4 │     3  c
   5 │   200  last line

julia> pushfirst!(df, (300, "first line"))
6×2 DataFrame
 Row │ x      y
     │ Int64  String
─────┼───────────────────
   1 │   300  first line
   2 │     1  a
   3 │   100  new line
   4 │     2  b
   5 │     3  c
   6 │   200  last line
```

Comment: The `insert!.` approach no longer works in Julia 1.7 and DataFrames v1.3.4. Is there a modification?

Comment: I added an edit with examples for DataFrames.jl 1.4 - use `insert!`, `push!`, or `pushfirst!` now.