# How to insert a new row in julia at specific index

Tags: julia, julia-dataframe

I am using julia 1.4, I have a df like below. I want to add a new row to an existing dataframe at specific index. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51505007/julia-dataframes-insert-new-row-at-specific-index) but it seems old.
I am using `DataFrame(insert!.(eachcol(df), index, value))` to insert a row. I feel it's over performing. Because, it uses `eachcol` iterator and on top of result it converts array into `Dataframe`.

Sample Input:

```
│ Row │ x1       │ x2        │ x3       │ x4        │
│     │ Float64  │ Float64   │ Float64  │ Float64   │
├─────┼──────────┼───────────┼──────────┼───────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.236197 │ 0.509669  │ 0.353128 │ 0.615519  │
│ 2   │ 0.976431 │ 0.771457  │ 0.282455 │ 0.979453  │
│ 3   │ 0.445266 │ 0.0327924 │ 0.450912 │ 0.0135655 │
```

Expected Output:

```
4×4 DataFrame
│ Row │ x1       │ x2        │ x3       │ x4        │
│     │ Float64  │ Float64   │ Float64  │ Float64   │
├─────┼──────────┼───────────┼──────────┼───────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.236197 │ 0.509669  │ 0.353128 │ 0.615519  │
│ 2   │ 10.0     │ 12.0      │ 14.0     │ 16.0      │
│ 3   │ 0.976431 │ 0.771457  │ 0.282455 │ 0.979453  │
│ 4   │ 0.445266 │ 0.0327924 │ 0.450912 │ 0.0135655 │
```

Comment: You do not need to add `DataFrame` wrapper on top of the result of `insert!`. I have updated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51505007/julia-dataframes-insert-new-row-at-specific-index to make it clear.

Comment: I marked it as duplicate as I have updated the old answer.